# Chart.js Polar Area Chart scale background color

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've set the `Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#FFF'`

I now have this affect
[image]

Does anyone know the correct Chart option (presumably) to turn that white square transparent?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the `backdropColor` for the specific scaleType i.e.

```
Chart.scaleService.defaults.radialLinear.ticks.backdropColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
```